# line break problem

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am forcing a text file download but I don't get a line break in the text file. It shows `\r\n`

```
header("Content-type: text/text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testi.txt");
foreach($results as $result){
echo $result['xrt'].' '.$result['CMP'].'    '.$result['Add'].' '.$result['AFG'].'   '.'Times'.' '.$result['range'].'\r\n';
}
```

Comment: No, "\r\n" would do it. PHP_EOL changes depending on which plattform your script get's executed. If it's a linux based server it will contain "\n" but if it's your windows testbed it will be "\r\n". So keep it save and use "\r\n". Otherwise you might get surprises when you move your site from one server to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `PHP_EOL`

```
header("Content-type: text/text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testi.txt");

foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['xrt'].'   '.$result['CMP'].'  '.$result['Add'].' '.$result['AFG'].'   '.'Times'.' '.$result['range'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

Or if you must type them, use: `"\r\n"`

```
header("Content-type: text/text");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testi.txt");

foreach($results as $result){
    echo $result['xrt'].'   '.$result['CMP'].'  '.$result['Add'].' '.$result['AFG'].'   '.'Times'.' '.$result['range']."\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use double quotes:

```
"\n\r"
```

check here for more info
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double